# Can Python Interpreter be run remotely on Windows with PSSession

Tags: windows-10, powershell, python

Running the Python Interpreter on a particular Windows machine locally and remotely using ssh works great.  However, Windows does not have a Linux `screen` equivalent, so I want to switch to using PSSession to remote into this Windows machine so I can start jobs, then disconnect and reconnect later to get the results.

Starting `python` on this Windows computer from a local terminal or remote terminal with an ssh connection works as expected.  However, when I successfully connect to this same Windows computer with PSSession and can run many powershell commands and scripts without issue, when I type `python` nothing happens.  Only the PSSession remote command prompt is returned on the next line.  There are no errors reported.

Can the Python Interpreter be run remotely on Windows with PSSession?

Do I need to set additional [PSSessionOptions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption?view=powershell-6)?

Current connection sequence:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$s_opt = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout -1
$s1 = New-PSSession -ComputerName 100.100.100.100 -Name sess1 -SessionOption $s_opt -Credential $cred 
Enter-PSSession $s1
```